# How can I filter a price range with two inputs using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried too many ways to filter them based on the inputs but still not working. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a way just by using the filter or i might also misused the forEach method. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the code I am using.

```js
let category = document.querySelector('.category');
const searchMin = Number(document.getElementById('min').value);
const searchMax = Number(document.getElementById('max').value);


const filteredPrices = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  Array.from(category.children)
    .filter(price => {
      if (Number(price.innerText) > searchMin && Number(price.innerText) < searchMax) {
        price.style.display = "block"
      } else {
        price.style.display = "none";
      }
    })
};

const resetForm = () => {
  Array.from(category.children)
    .forEach(li => li.removeAttribute('style'))
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="main" onsubmit="filteredPrices(event)">
    <input type="text" id="min" placeholder="min" value="20">
    <input type="text" id="max" placeholder="max" value="70">
    <button type="submit">show</button>
    <button type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" class="button">reset</button>
  </form>


  <ul class="category">
    <li>
      <h2>kitkat</h2>
      <p>20</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>snikers</h2>
      <p>40</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>maltesers</h2>
      <p>50</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>milka</h2>
      <p>60</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>tadela</h2>
      <p>70</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>bounty</h2>
      <p>80</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: any exception right now?

Comment: this will never match since you are matching a number with WHOLE STRING not number alone

Comment: where you have `.filter(price => /* ... */)`, the price is the `<li>...</li>`. So if you pass the inner text of that to `Number`, you will probably get `NaN`. And in this case, since you're not returning anything but merely performing side effects, go back to using `forEach` instead of `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code a little, you were on the right path for the most part. I moved the values into the `filterPrices` function and changed the `category` variable since there was no use of it minus getting the list nodes which is now contained in `items`

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.category li');

const filteredPrices = event =>
{
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const searchMin = Number(document.getElementById('min').value);
  const searchMax = Number(document.getElementById('max').value);

  items.forEach(item =>
  {
    const price = Number(item.querySelector('p').textContent);
    
    if (price < searchMin || price > searchMax)
      item.style.display = 'none';
    else
      item.style.display = 'block';
  });
};

const resetForm = () =>
{
  items.forEach(li => li.style.display = 'block');
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="main" onsubmit="filteredPrices(event)">
    <input type="text" id="min" placeholder="min" value="20">
    <input type="text" id="max" placeholder="max" value="70">
    <button type="submit">show</button>
    <button type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" class="button">reset</button>
  </form>


  <ul class="category">
    <li>
      <h2>kitkat</h2>
      <p>20</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>snikers</h2>
      <p>40</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>maltesers</h2>
      <p>50</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>milka</h2>
      <p>60</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>tadela</h2>
      <p>70</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>bounty</h2>
      <p>80</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```